# Error while booting Ubuntu 20.04 after installing Gradle

Tags: ubuntu, gradle

After installing Gradle 7.2 in Ubuntu 20.04 when booting I'm prompted with the following error

```
Error found while loading /etc/profile:

/etc/profile.d/gradle.sh: Line 1: /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh: Permission denied

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

`Gradle Info`

[image: Gradle Version]

`gradle.sh info`

[image: Gradle.sh Info]

Is there something I've skipped during installation/configuration that could cause this issue?

Comment: Did you try chmod +x on the file?

Comment: Yes I did, but this corrupted my system. I got exception shell level to high and I cant login to ubuntu anymore